# Git update or clone

Tags: git

As part of a script that collects external dependencies for a project, I want to check if a dependency is available at the right version.

Currently, I check if the folder exists, and if it does, fetch and check out to the version and if not, clone at that version.

I have something like this:

```
if [ -d $REPO_DIR ]; then
    echo "Updating to [$(REPO_VERSION)]";
    git --git-dir=$(REPO_DIR)/.git --work-tree=$(REPO_DIR) fetch
    git --git-dir=$(REPO_DIR)/.git --work-tree=$(REPO_DIR) checkout $(REPO_VERSION)
else
    echo "Cloning to [$(REPO_VERSION)]";
    git --git-dir=$(REPO_DIR)/.git --work-tree=$(REPO_DIR) clone --branch $(REPO_VERSION) $REPO_ADDRESS $REPO_DIR 2> /dev/null;
fi
```

Wondering if there is a more git native way of doing this?

-- Edit --

To add more context, for the project, these dependencies are already managed by a package manager (`pip`). The only reason I am doing this, is for building a docker image (which cannot install those libraries via pip since they are private repositories).

That's why, I wouldn't use `submodules`, since the dependency is already managed without the submodule overhead.

Comment: Be wary of race conditions.

Comment: Why not using bower? grunt? gulp and so on? why do you do it with git?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `git submodule/subtree`.

Submodule or subtree are git projects inside another git project.

The concept its that you have a standalone code which is a fully separated git repository. This way you can manage 3rd party code inside your main project.

Here is a sample on how your project will look like using submodule.

### [image]

### subtree

The main difference between subtree to submodule is where the code is managed.   Under submodules it a seperated repository while using subtree the code is part of your main repository.

Comment: The reason these are not submodules is that they are already installed using a dependency manager for the application. The only reason I want to manually fetch them is for caching and building a docker image.